# Non-Java JMX client

Tags: java, rmi, jmx, jconsole, mbeans

Is it possible to create a JMX client that doesn't run on the JVM?
From my understanding JMX is a protocol on top of other protocols (like RMI) so it should be possible to create a C or Go client. Any reason why this hasn't been done?

I am aware of Jolokia and realise it can be used as a proxy.

Comment: All the code behind JMX is open-source, so I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be possible to reimplement it in a different language. I guess this hasn't been done because there's a lot of code and no one needed it before.

Comment: @yole That's not the question. The question is whether you can write a *client* in another language, not reimplement the whole thing.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Reimplementing the whole thing doesn't make sense because it's tied to the JVM internals.

Comment: RMI means serialized java classes.  You need to emulate that to work with other platforms.

Comment: ALso consider looking at https://stackoverflow.com/q/5106847/53897

Comment: For sake of clarity, I would recommend jpype for python users. It still instantiates the jvm but it runs under python as well. https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: JMX has, or had, an HTTP interface.